# Print modified list values using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Having a list like the following one

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

values.add(1);
values.add(0);
values.add(1);
values.add(1);
values.add(0);
```

I want to print the elements `> 0` adding them a value, for example `10`, by using Java 8 Stream. For example:

```
values.stream()
    .filter(val -> val > 0)
    // HERE add 10
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?

Comment: If you convert the List into a Stream, you cannot modify the List in place, you will get a new List

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I edited the question. I don't really need to modify the values, I just need to print them adding another value, is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Check Matthew's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the map operation

```
values.stream()
      .filter(val -> val>0)
      .map(x -> x+10)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you need to keep the values, do

```
List<Integer> newValues = values.stream()
                                .filter(val -> val>0)
                                .map(x -> x+10)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: map will not change values in list, just print value + 10

Comment: He said that he only needed to print the values.  I have modified the answer to address the need to save the values, however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print and save new data in one go you can use `peek()` like below -

```
List<Integer> newValues = myList.stream().filter(val -> val>0).map(x -> x+10)
                .peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
values = StreamSupport.stream(values)
    .filter(val -> val > 0)
    .forEach(val -> val += 10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then you can use:

```
values.stream()
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: forEach is terminal, so you can't chain the collect method after it.

Comment: I don't know which API you are looking, but there's no method `stream` in the `StreamSupport` class that accepts a list or collection as parameter in the official documentation.